# Insert a bean into a Converter

Tags: jsf-2, dependency-injection

I have the following ApplicationScoped bean

```
package es.caib.gesma.gesman.data;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import es.caib.gesma.gesman.ejb.Dao;

@ManagedBean(name="priorityList")
@ApplicationScoped
public class PriorityList {

  @EJB
  Dao daoEjb;

  private List<Priority> priorities = null;

    public PriorityList() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void refresh() {
      this.priorities = daoEjb.findPriorities();
    }

    public List<Priority> getPriorities() {
      return this.priorities;
    }

    public Priority fromId(int id) {
      for(Priority priority : this.priorities) {
        if (priority.getId() == id) {
          return priority;
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
```

I try to inject that bean inside a Converter

```
package es.caib.gesma.gesman.data.converter;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.ConverterException;

import es.caib.gesma.gesman.data.Priority;
import es.caib.gesma.gesman.data.PriorityList;

@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class PriorityConverter implements Converter {

  @ManagedProperty("#{priorityList}")
  private PriorityList priorityList;

  @Override
  public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2) {
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2) {
    ...
  }

  public void setPriorityList(PriorityList priorityList) {
    System.out.println("SET PRIORITYLIST " + priorityList);
    this.priorityList = priorityList;
  }

}
```

Whenever I try to access the property, it is null. The setter is never called.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135942/managedproperty-not-injected-in-facesconverter) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737623/how-do-i-get-a-managed-bean-inside-an-unmanaged-object), it looks like it is not possible to inject the bean the usual way (please correct me if I am wrong). There is any alternative so I avoid having to get the entire list of values from the EJB (= database access) each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to pull this bean out from the HttpSession (it works for me in PhaseListener with SessionScoped bean)

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
SessionForm sessionBean = (SessionForm) session.getAttribute("priorityList");
```

Or if I may borrow article from BalusC about [JSF communication](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html), on the bottom is described how to make a converter from ManagedBean (so you could easily inject your ApplicationScoped bean there)

Comment: Close. It is an applicationscoped bean, so I had to use `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("priorityList")`

Answer (score 1):

You can't (currently) inject dependencies into converters. However, if you can use Seam 3, the [seam-faces](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/FacesModule) module will enable this. You don't need to do anything special, just have the seam-faces JAR (and any of its dependencies) in the classpath and injection into converters will magically work. Just watch out for other unintended side-effects (I've noticed differences in transaction boundaries when the seam-persistence JAR is in the classpath).