# RequestFilter and SessionBean for authorisation

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters, managed-bean, session-scope

I am using jsf 2.0 on websphere application server 8.

I have a request filter which authorizes an user. The user authenticates himself against an WebSEAL.
The userrole is saved in a MySQL DB.
My Requestfilter gets the user principal from the httpServletRequest on each request.
Then I look which role the user has (in the DB).

That is very poor, because I have a DB query on each request.

To improve that, I want to implement a SessionBean which contains the username and role.
My problem is, that I cant get the sessionbean from my requestfilter.
I've tryed to use the sessionbean as managesproperty in the filterclass.

But I always get a Nullpointerexception because the sessionbean is never called before.

So how can I do this? Is this a wrong way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get JSF managed bean by name in any Servlet related class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/get-jsf-managed-bean-by-name-in-any-servlet-related-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF stores `@SessionScoped @ManagedBean`s as an attribute of the `HttpSession`. So, inside the `Filter` they are available as follows:

```
HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession();
SessionBean sessionBean = (SessionBean) session.getAttribute("sessionBean");
```

You however need to take into account that this approach won't auto-create the bean when it doesn't exist in the scope yet. This will be the case when the filter is invoked for the first time on a fresh new HTTP session. The `Filtler` is namely invoked *before* the `FacesServlet`. You'd then need to create the session bean *yourself*.

```
HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession();
SessionBean sessionBean = (SessionBean) session.getAttribute("sessionBean");

if (sessionBean == null) {
    sessionBean = new SessionBean();
    session.setAttribute("sessionBean", sessionBean);
}

// ...

sessionBean.setRole(role);

// ...
```

JSF won't override it with a new instance whenever it *already* exist in the session scope, but just reuse the very same instance as created in the `Filter`.

In case you're already using CDI `@Named` to manage beans instead of the in JSF 2.3 deprecated and Faces 4.0 removed `@ManagedBean`, then simply `@Inject` it in the `Filter`.

#### See also:

- [Get JSF managed bean by name in any Servlet related class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/get-jsf-managed-bean-by-name-in-any-servlet-related-class)

Answer (score 0):

See my similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596265/insert-a-bean-into-a-converter/10596588#10596588), you should be able to obtain your SessionBean this way

**EDIT**

Or you can try this approach

```
 HttpSession session = (req (HttpServletRequest)).getSession();
 MyManagedBean myManagedBean = session.getAttribute("myManagedBean");`
```

Or you could use PhaseListener instead of your filter. See this nice [article](http://devgrok.blogspot.cz/2009/07/access-control-using-phaselistener.html) about using PhaseListener for securing your app.

Comment: Now I get here the nullpointerexception: session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);

Comment: No, you will obtain the SessionBean in your filter (which is saved in the session) and then you can normally call methods like it was injected with ManagedProperty.

Comment: There is no SessionBean in my Session. The Constructor of the session is never called...

Comment: What objectyou a null pointer exception?Which approach did you try(see my edit)?You have to be more specific to get advice...